# How to find methods which are only defined in a subclass, in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, subclass

Is there a clean way to get methods only defined in a subclass that not defined in parent class?

```
class Parent(object):
     def method_of_parent(self):
         pass
class SubClass(Parent):
     def method_of_subclass(self):
         pass

# desired:
>>> print(get_subclass_methods(SubClass))
['method_of_subclass',]
```

Comment: Look in `SubClass.__dict__`?

Comment: contains the parent dict also.

Comment: No it doesn't - `mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'method_of_subclass': <function SubClass.method_of_subclass at 0x107291730>})`. No `method_of_parent`.

Comment: I`m sorry i forget to mention python 2.7

Comment: ...`dict_proxy({'method_of_subclass': <function method_of_subclass at 0x10ed39410>, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})`

Comment: If a method is defined on the parent class and *overridden* on the subclass, should it appear in the list?

Comment: @kindall no problem

Answer (score 3):

I think there are many corner cases but here is one of solutions.

```
import inspect


class Parent(object):
     def method_of_parent(self):
         pass
class SubClass(Parent):
     def method_of_subclass(self):
         pass

def get_subclass_methods(child_cls):
    parents = inspect.getmro(child_cls)[1:]
    parents_methods = set()
    for parent in parents:
        members = inspect.getmembers(parent, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
        parents_methods.update(members)

    child_methods = set(inspect.getmembers(child_cls, predicate=inspect.ismethod))

    child_only_methods = child_methods - parents_methods
    return [m[0] for m in child_only_methods]

print(get_subclass_methods(SubClass))
```

Result

```
['method_of_subclass']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using a few ingredients:

- The [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function
- sets' [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) method
- The built-in [`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__) attribute

```py
class Parent(object):
     def method_of_parent(self):
         pass
class SubClass(Parent):
     def method_of_subclass(self):
         pass

def get_subclass_methods(cls):
    methods = set(dir(cls()))
    unique_methods = methods.difference(*(dir(base()) for base in cls.__bases__))
    return list(unique_methods)

print(get_subclass_methods(SubClass))
```

Gives:

```py
['method_of_subclass']
```

---

This also supports multiple inheritance so also doing:

```py
class SubSubClass(SubClass):
    def method_of_subsubclass(self):
        pass

print(get_subclass_methods(SubSubClass))
```

Will give:

```py
['method_of_subsubclass']
```

Comment: `dir()` also works on the class itself, not just on an instance of a class. Using `dir(cls)` and `dir(base)` over `dir(cls()) ` resp. `dir(base())`,  has the advantage that the code works even if the `__init__` method takes parameters.